# uploading document causes error first time

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I am having this error where the user is allowed to upload a document but the first time when it's chosen it causes an error but if the user does it the second time, the document is uploaded successfully.

The function first called it PickDocument btw.

The error I'm getting is the alert from FilePArser function

this is my related code:

```
const [userOut, setUserOut] = useState("")
const pickDocument = async () => {
        console.log('pic Doc')
        try {
            let input = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
                type: "text/plain",
            })
            setUserOut(await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(input.uri))
            createLoans()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const fileParser = () => {
        console.log('file parser')
        const parsedLoans = [];
        var newUserOut = userOut;

        if (newUserOut.length == 0) {
            Alert.alert('wrong document','Try Again')
            return;
        }
        //remove the grants
        var grantPos = newUserOut.search("Grant Type:");
        var pos = newUserOut.search("Loan Type:");
        //hopefully just the loans now
        newUserOut = newUserOut.slice(pos, grantPos)

        while (newUserOut.length > 0) {
            var lastPos = newUserOut.lastIndexOf("Loan Type:");
            parsedLoans.push(newUserOut.slice(lastPos, newUserOut.length));
            newUserOut = newUserOut.slice(0, lastPos);
        }
        //console.log('parsed loans: ' + parsedLoans)
        return parsedLoans;
    };

    const createLoans = () => {
        console.log('create loans')
        const newLoans = fileParser();
        const title= 'Loan Amount:$'
        const interest = 'Loan Interest Rate:'

        for(let i =1; i <= newLoans.length; i++){
            let loan = newLoans[i]
            let goalTitle=loan.substring(loan.indexOf(title)+title.length,loan.indexOf('Loan Disbursed Amount:'))
            //console.log("goalTitle: " + goalTitle)
            let interestRate = loan.substring(loan.indexOf(interest)+interest.length,loan.indexOf('Loan Repayment Plan Type')-1)
            //console.log("Interest rate: "+ interestRate)
            let years = 10
            let paidOff = 50
            setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
            let id =i
            addGoalHandler(goalTitle,interestRate,years,paidOff,id)
        }
        return

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to use 'useState' as if it's a global variable. Setting the state does not immediately mutate the state values, it sets a pending request to update the state of your application and re-render it as soon as possible. Therefore it can't be relied upon to be finished updating by the next line, like a regular variable can. See this question/answer for more details: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: I looked at it but Im having trouble on how to apply this to useState instead of setState. Do you have any pointers